# RVIZ tutorial error ( dir 'include' is neither an absolute directory nor exists)

Tags: ros, rviz, rosrun, ros-groovy, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the rviz tutorials on ROS wiki
The basic shapes tutorial

Whenever I do the catkin_make in the folder I have made with the command

```
catkin_create_pkg using_markers roscpp visualization_msgs
```

it gives me the following error. What should I do?

```
 The specified base path "/home/asfandyar/using_markers" contains a CMakeLists.txt but "catkin_make" must be invoked in the root of workspace
```

I tried moving the CMakeLists.txt to the src folder and then I used catkin_make and it gave me the following error.

```
 CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:314 (message):
      catkin_package() include dir 'include' is neither an absolute directory nor
      exists relative to '/home/asfandyar/using_markers1/src'
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
      CMakeLists.txt:50 (catkin_package)
    
    
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Invoking "cmake" failed
```

What should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65285/rviz-tutorial-error-(-dir-%27include%27-is-neither-an-absolute-directory-nor-exists)/) by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 729 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. I moved the CMakeList.txt to the src file and I made an install folder there. This is a simple hack and I would not recommend this, but it worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) with karma: 729 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1